# LibGDX scale Textbutton then clicked

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to change the size of the textbutton if the user clicked down on it, and if the user dont touch it the textbutton go on the normal size. it would be perfect with a slow animation so that the user sees the well.

here my code:

```
textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    textButtonStyle.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(texture));
    textButtonStyle.font = font_var;
    buttonHighscore = new TextButton("Highscore", textButtonStyle);
    stage.addActor(buttonHighscore);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that it is not possible to do this with `ButtonStyle` but I would attach my own `ClickListener` to it and adjust the size of the actor or whatever you want to do with it. `ClickListener` offers `isOver` functionality but since you want to set it back to original numbers we use `enter` and `exit`.

```
    button.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
            super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);

            if (fromActor != null)
                fromActor.setSize(overSize, overSize);
        }
        @Override
        public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
            super.exit(event, x, y, pointer, toActor);

            if (toActor != null)
                toActor.setSize(defaultSize, defaultSize);
        }
    });
```

Depending on how your stage is layout this might or might not work. Maybe you need to grab the parent of the actor within the listener and set these widths. For a simple button in a table filling the stage/screen this works for me.

You can use `Actor` actions for the animation. No time to give you a example now but just Google it, it's easy to implement.

Comment: it shows me a error by super.enter and super.exit. this methods does not exist

Comment: i use a change listener

Comment: Accept my answer if it helps and perhaps +1 if you are happy with it ;)